# How to install latest STABLE version of a Javascript package via a package manager?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, bower, package-managers

How to install latest stable version of a Javascript package via a package manager?

(no alphas, betas, etc.)

I tried NPM and did not find a solution. [This question is similar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076504/how-to-find-the-latest-stable-version-of-an-npm-package)

I tried Bower and find nothing. Here is a  [question with no answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683243/bower-install-latest-stable-dependencies)

Please help. Which package manager should I choose? Maybe there are another options around?

PS

For example: knockout.js, npm givers beta for latest. I don't want beta! I also would like to set the same limitation for dependencies - pull only stable versions.

Comment: You can checkout their npm page and see which version is stable and install that version only

Comment: I can, but it defeats the purpose of a package manager, because I need to do stuff manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a package without specifying a version will always install the latest version published to npm, including pre-releases (alpha, beta etc.):

```
npm install knockout
```

However, if you **specify the version range, even only as a wildcard `*`**, pre-release versions are explicitly excluded:

```
npm install knockout@*
```

---

See [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#prerelease-tags) for more info. Also, you can test this in [npm's semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/).